# JPA Hibernate EnableJpaAuditing isUpdateNecessary

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I used the @EnableJpaAuditing, @LastModifiedDate,@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class) provided by JPA to record the audit information, but found that when my entity field did not change, JPA would not send update SQL statements to the database. I looked at the source code and saw that hibernate would call an isUpdateNecessary to decide whether to send update SQL to the database.

```
if ( isUpdateNecessary( event, mightBeDirty ) ) {
            substitute = scheduleUpdate( event ) || substitute;
        }

        if ( status != Status.DELETED ) {
            // now update the object .. has to be outside the main if block above (because of collections)
            if ( substitute ) {
                persister.setPropertyValues( entity, values );
            }

            // Search for collections by reachability, updating their role.
            // We don't want to touch collections reachable from a deleted object
            if ( persister.hasCollections() ) {
                new FlushVisitor( session, entity ).processEntityPropertyValues( values, types );
            }
        }
```

As a result, my audit information will not be updated. What should I do if I want to execute the update SQL no matter what. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Think more about the purpose of your autiting, if no value has change why do you want to make an update ?

Comment: Other question, let suppose you make the update you wanted, without changin any value, the new "lastModifiedDate" will be wrong because it will be the date of an "no modification save". Is thit that you want ?

Comment: @Zorglube Thank you very much for your answer. I know it's a little strange. But I do need to do that under certain scenarios.

Comment: In this case I'm I recommend you to use a dirty but working workaround, just change an value un the entity and save it.